# Problems to refresh my migration on Laravel, error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Tags: laravel, migration

I was making a project in laravel 9 using docker to host the project, and I want to refresh my migration but it keeping  given me this error message:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: No such host is known.  (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\Users\giova\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\star-fox\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:759
    755▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    756▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    757▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    758▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 759▕             throw new QueryException(
    760▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    761▕             );
    762▕         }
    763▕     }
```

I already try change my .env in a lot different way but didn´t solve, my .env now is this one:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=laravel
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

yes I check the container the msql is running,
Can someone help me ?

A try canhge the local host to

```
127.0.0.1
```

to

laravel

to

localhost

but none of there works

Can someone   help fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Go inside of your App Container and run it in there.

Also i cant see if your mysql is a Container himself.